# How to handle null values during binary search?

Tags: c#, null, binary-search

What's the best way to go about handling `null`s during a binary search over a `List<string>` (well, it *would* be a `List<string>` if I could read all the values out beforehand)?

```
int previous = 0;
int direction = -1;
if (itemToCompare == null) {
    previous = mid;

    for (int tries = 0; tries < 2; tries++) {
        mid += direction;
        itemToCompare = GetItem(mid);
        while (itemToCompare == null && insideInclusiveRange(min, max, mid)) {
            mid += direction;
            itemToCompare = GetItem(mid);
        }
        if (!insideInclusiveRange(min, max, mid)) {
            /* Reached an endpoint without finding anything,
                try the other direction. */
            mid = previous;
            direction = -direction;
        } else if (itemToCompare != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently doing something like the above - if null is encountered, then linearly search in a direction until either *non-null* or *beyond endpoint* is encountered, if no success then repeat in other direction. In the actual code I'm getting `direction` from the previous comparison result, and  `GetItem()` caches the values it retrieves. Is there an easier way, without making an intermediate list of non-null values (takes far too long for my purposes because the `GetItem()` function above is slow)?

I guess I'm asking if there's a smarter way to handle null values than to degrade to a linear search. In all likelihood there will only be a small percentage of nulls (1-5%), but it's *possible* for there to be sequences of 100s of null.

Edit - The data looks something like this

```
         aa         aaa
b        bb         bbb
c        cc
d                   ddd
```

where each row is a separate object, and not all cells are guaranteed to be filled. The user needs to be able to search across an entire row (so that both "bb" and "bbb" would match the entire second row). Querying each object is slow enough that a linear search will not work. For the same reason, creating a new list without nulls is not really feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a reason to actually select/find a `null` value (not sure what that means as `null` is a singleton and binary search is often most desirable on *unique values*), consider *not allowing them in the list at all*.

---

[**Previous answer:** After reflecting on the question more I have decided that `null`s likely have no place in the problem-space -- take bits and parts as appropriate.]

If nulls are desired, just sort the list such that null values are first (or last) and update the logic correctly -- then just make sure not to invoke a method upon any of the `null` values ;-)

This should have little overall impact since a sort is already required. If items are changed to `null` -- which sounds like an icky side-effect! -- then just "compact" the List (e.g. "remove" the null item). I would, however, just *not modify* the sorted list unless there is a good reason.

Binary search is only really designed/suitable for *(entirely) sorted data*. No point turning it into a binary-maybe-linear search.

Happy coding.

Comment: I added some information about why I can't use a plain linear search and why I can't pre-process the list.